# Install new Ubuntu OS in a partition of my Mac

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, mac, refind

Some days ago I dual booted my Macbook Pro 15 inch 2017 with Ubuntu. Now, as the Ubuntu I installed following this tutorial https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-mac/ is not suitable for my task, I have decided to install a new Ubuntu version (one that solves issues with drivers for Mac) and I don't know how to remove the old Ubuntu for the new one without removing the partition. The ideal case scenario would be to clean the partition without removing it, and install the new OS in the fresh partition.

Comment: What versions do you want to go to and from?

Comment: If you use the Something Else install option and choose the existing partition as / (root) and check formatting it will totally erase it and install new version into that partition. If you have a separate partition for /home you DO NOT choose/check the format box so it does not erase your data in /home.

Comment: I think I did as @oldfred, but is strange because when I go to disc utilities in Ubuntu it says I have occupied 8 GB even though adding all the subfolders sizes are 6 GB so that is why I thought I still had the previous version. Another strange thing is that I boot with ReFind and in there appear me two ubuntu discs: EFI\ubuntu\grub64.efi and boot\vmlinuz-4.15.0-43-generic from 69 GiB. Moreover the partition is 75 GB so is strange that appears 69GB

Comment: If you want to see what is where with lots of details. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair If you want someone to review the install, then post the link it gives.